# Javascript getDay() returns wrong day

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

As I'm making a form which uses a date to determine it's field value I came across the following problem. In my form I'm using a 'select' input with some options and a field where one can enter a date. The value of a certain option in the 'select' input depends on what date is entered (the value represents a price, which is higher in the weekends).

At first I used an input type="date" for the date field and wrote a javascript function to get the day of week to determine weekends, this worked fine. But when I implemented the jQuery datepicker widget the input type only seemed to work when I changed it to type="text". From here on the getDay() method started to return the wrong day. This has resulted into whenever I pick a date it returns the wrong price because it doesn't pick the correct day of the week.

I think the problem is that the date isn't read correctly because it is returned as a string and not as a date, and therefore returns an invalid date. I spent quite some hours looking for a solution and tried several possible solutions but so far it still doesn't work.

Here's the part of the code that is used to check the date:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="tukdatum" class="reservinput" value="" name="voorkeursdatum" maxlength="10" onchange="calculateTotal()" />

<select id="activiteit" name="activiteit" onchange="calculateTotal()">
  <option value="bowling" id="bowling">Bowling bij Pins&Pints € 17.50 p.p. (€ 25,- in de weekenden)</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var tuk_activiteiten = new Array();
tuk_activiteiten["bowling"]=17.50;
tuk_activiteiten["bowlingWE"]=25;

function checkDate()
{
    var inputdate = document.getElementById("tukdatum").value;
    var tukdate = new Date(inputdate);
    if (tukdate.getDay() == 6 || tukdate.getDay() == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("bowling").value = "bowlingWE";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("bowling").value = "bowling";
    }
}
```

jQuery for datepicker:

```
$(function(){
  $.datepicker.setDefaults(
    $.extend( $.datepicker.regional[ 'nl' ] )
  );
  $( '#tukdatum' ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      minDate: '+1',
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
  });
});
```

So basically what I want it to do is check if the date entered by the datepicker is in the weekend (if true, then option value = 25, else option value = 17.50). Please note that the form is written in Dutch (ie. id/class names etc.).

Comment: What *does* it return? It's good to include some examples of what's actually happening vs. what's expected.

Comment: It would also be good to just slim the whole thing down to just the relevant part(s). Preferably with a snippet or fiddle. The only part of interest is the `checkDate` section and the html for `tukdatum`, right?

Comment: @DaveNewton At the moment when I am using the datepicker it returns an invalid date, meaning it binds the value 25 to the wrong day of the week. It is supposed to bind the value 25 to Saturday and Sunday and for all the other days of the week the value 17.50. Right now it binds the value 17.50 to almost every date I pick, except for some certain dates (ie. Sunday 01-03-2015, Thursday 05-03-2015).

Comment: @MattBurland already did that, but I'll slim it down some more if this is too much code. As I'm not a 100% sure where the error is I just posted every part that has anything to do with it. I'll try to get a fiddle to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you are using the correct method to get the date from the datepicker. In your `checkDate()` function instead of this

```
var inputdate = document.getElementById("tukdatum").value;
var tukdate = new Date(inputdate);
```

you can use

```
var tukdate = $("#tukdatum").datepicker("getDate");
```

This is because getDate returns a date object which does not need to be parsed using `new Date`.

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tepizoheqa/3/edit) - Check out the console

[Documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, returns an "Invalid Date". Any ideas why?

Comment: @MozillaFox 'Invalid date' is an issue with the `new Date` code that you assign to `var tukdate`. Since getDate returns a `Date` object (in the doc the return type is at the top right) there is no need to have `var tukdate = new Date(inputdate);`. You could just change it to `var tukdate = $("#tukdatum").datepicker("getDate");` and leave out inputdate all together. I've edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: alright I tried that, for some reason that only returns " [object Object] ", possibly because it's trying to get a date from a text string?

Comment: @MozillaFox Which part is returning Object? Check out the JSBin in the answer (open up the console). Calling `.datepicker("getDate"); ` returns a date object where `getDay()` would work

Comment: When I changed the code I also added another input type text, to check what the var tukdate would return I added this:     document.getElementById("divObj").value = tukdate;  this returned Object.  As for the JSBin, I can see it returns a date in the devtools console

Comment: @MozillaFox For error checking use `console.log` (like in the JSBin) and open up your developer console in your browser to see the output (JSBin has a tab at the top to see console output). Also, don't assign to a div using `.value`, if you want to change the value of the div use `.textContent` as in `document.getElementById('divObj').textContent = tukdate;` and you should see a full output of the `Date` object

Comment: alright I think I've got it working now. I changed the .value  to .textContent as you suggested and now it displays the selected time properly and also adds the correct values to the option. Thanks a lot for your quick replies! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thats great, no problem